# How to combine two results and pipe it to next step in apache-beam pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

See below code snippet,
I want `["metric1", "metric2"]` to be my input for RunTask.process. However it was run twice with "metric1" and "metric2" respectively

```
def run():
  
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

  root = p | 'Get source' >> beam.Create([
      "source_name" # maybe ["source_name"] makes more sense since my process function takes an array as an input?
  ])

  metric1 = root | "compute1" >> beam.ParDo(RunLongCompute(myarg="1")) #let's say it returns ["metic1"]
  metric2 = root | "compute2" >> beam.ParDo(RunLongCompute(myarg="2")) #let's say it returns ["metic2"]

  metric3 = (metric1, metric2) | beam.Flatten() | beam.ParDo(RunTask()) # I want ["metric1", "metric2"] to be my input for RunTask.process. However it was run twice with "metric1" and "metric2" respectively
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I understand that you want to join two PCollections in a way they follow this syntax : *['element1','element2']*. In order to achieve that you can use [CoGroupByKey()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms) instead of [Flatten()](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms).

Considering your code snippet, the syntax would:

```
def run():
  
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
  p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

  root = p | 'Get source' >> beam.Create([
      "source_name" # maybe ["source_name"] makes more sense since my process function takes an array as an input?
  ])

  metric1 = root | "compute1" >> beam.ParDo(RunLongCompute(myarg="1")) #let's say it returns ["metic1"]
  metric2 = root | "compute2" >> beam.ParDo(RunLongCompute(myarg="2")) #let's say it returns ["metic2"]

  metric3 = (
       (metric1, metric2) 
       | beam.CoGroupByKey() 
       | beam.ParDo(RunTask()) 
 )
```

I would like to point out the difference between Flatten() and CoGroupByKey().

***1) Flatten()*** receives two or more PCollections, which stores the same data type, and merge them into one  logical PCollection. For example,

```
import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam import Flatten, Create, ParDo, Map

p = beam.Pipeline()

adress_list = [
    ('leo', 'George St. 32'),
    ('ralph', 'Pyrmont St. 30'),
    ('mary', '10th Av.'),
    ('carly', 'Marina Bay 1'),
]
city_list = [
    ('leo', 'Sydney'),
    ('ralph', 'Sydney'),
    ('mary', 'NYC'),
    ('carly', 'Brisbane'),
]

street = p | 'CreateEmails' >> beam.Create(adress_list)
city = p | 'CreatePhones' >> beam.Create(city_list)

resul =(
    (street,city)
    |beam.Flatten()
    |ParDo(print)
)

p.run()
```

And the output,

```
('leo', 'George St. 32')
('ralph', 'Pyrmont St. 30')
('mary', '10th Av.')
('carly', 'Marina Bay 1')
('leo', 'Sydney')
('ralph', 'Sydney')
('mary', 'NYC')
('carly', 'Brisbane')
```

Notice that, both PCollections are in the output. However, one is appended to the other.

***2) CoGroupByKey()*** performs a relational join between two or more key value PCollections, which have the same key type. Using this method you will perform a join by key, not appending as done in Flatten(). Below is an example,

```
import apache_beam as beam

from apache_beam import Flatten, Create, ParDo, Map

p = beam.Pipeline()

address_list = [
    ('leo', 'George St. 32'),
    ('ralph', 'Pyrmont St. 30'),
    ('mary', '10th Av.'),
    ('carly', 'Marina Bay 1'),
]
city_list = [
    ('leo', 'Sydney'),
    ('ralph', 'Sydney'),
    ('mary', 'NYC'),
    ('carly', 'Brisbane'),
]

street = p | 'CreateEmails' >> beam.Create(address_list)
city = p | 'CreatePhones' >> beam.Create(city_list)

results = (
    (street, city)
    | beam.CoGroupByKey()
    |ParDo(print)
    #| beam.io.WriteToText('delete.txt')
    
)

p.run()
```

And the output,

```
('leo', (['George St. 32'], ['Sydney']))
('ralph', (['Pyrmont St. 30'], ['Sydney']))
('mary', (['10th Av.'], ['NYC']))
('carly', (['Marina Bay 1'], ['Brisbane']))
```

Notice that you need a *primary key* in order to join the results. Also, this output is what you expect in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use side input:

```
metrics3 = metric1 | beam.ParDo(RunTask(), metric2=beam.pvalue.AsIter(metric2))
```

in RunTask process():

```
def process(self, element_from_metric1, metric2):
  ...
```